# Selenium - how to click on white space area of the text box

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I'm trying to click the whitespace area of the text box rather than the text of the element. Is it possible in selenium or is there any other tricky approach?

[image]

The red arrow is placed where I want to click

HTML:

```
<td class="ms-srm-Field-Data-Print" data-height="24" id="stan_servicecategoryid_d">
    <div id="stan_servicecategoryid" data-attributename="stan_servicecategoryid" data-formid="bfef905d-acd0-4ee9-a900-2034792789c1" data-fdeid="PrimaryEntity" data-layout="0" tabindex="1070" isinline="true" lookupstyle="single" lookupdialogmultipleselect="0" isinlinenewenabled="1" showasbreadcrumbcontrol="0" showglobalquickcreate="0" openfullform="1" addlookupimagebutton="" role="application" entitylogicalname="stan_servicecategory" entitydisplayname="Service Category" entitytypecode="10041" allowfilteroff="0" disablequickfind="0" disableviewpicker="1" disablemru="1" isdeduplookup="0" availableviewids="{EA878523-32E1-49BB-B0C5-FF97230B5AF2}" resolveemailaddress="0" allowunresolvedpartiesonemailsend="0" defaultviewid="{152B96D2-3BF4-469E-8BB4-52C639E51E50}" class="ms-srm-Inline-Chrome lookup nvarchar" aria-label="Service Category Unique identifier for Service Category associated with Service Request.  test Select the Enter key to edit the lookup field, and the Control and Enter keys to open the link">
        <div class="ms-srm-Inline-Value ms-srm-Inline-Lookup" style="display: block;">
            <label data-for-id="stan_servicecategoryid_label" id="Service Category_label">
                <div class="ms-srm-div-NotVisible">Service Category</div>
            </label>
            <span>
                <span contenteditable="false" class="ms-srm-Lookup-Item" id="stan_servicecategoryid_lookupValue" title="test" tabindex="0">test</span>
                <div class="ms-srm-Inline-EditIcon keyboardFocusClass" id="stan_servicecategoryid_lookupSearchIconDiv" style="display: none;">
                    <img src="/_imgs/imagestrips/transparent_spacer.gif" id="stan_servicecategoryid_lookupSearchIcon" class="ms-srm-ImageStrip-search_normal ms-srm-InlineLookupEdit ms-srm-EditLookup-Image" alt="">
                </div>
            </span>
        </div>
        <div class="ms-srm-Inline-Edit ms-srm-Inline-Lookup" style="display: none;" lookuptypes="10041">
            <table id="stan_servicecategoryid_lookupTable" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" lookupid="stan_servicecategoryid" class="ms-srm-Lookup" aria-labelledby="stan_servicecategoryid_c stan_servicecategoryid_w" controlmode="normal" style="width: 100%;table-layout: fixed;">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td valign="top">
                            <div id="stan_servicecategoryid_lookupDiv" ime-mode="auto" class="ms-srm-Lookup ms-srm-InlineLookupEdit" tabindex="0" aria-labelledby="stan_servicecategoryid_lookupedit" title="Service Category Unique identifier for Service Category associated with Service Request.  test" style="display: block; background-color: rgb(171, 192, 231); width: 100%;">
                                <ul class="ms-srm-InlineLookupEdit">
                                    <li style="display: inline; white-space: nowrap;">
                                        <span class="ms-srm-Lookup-Item" contenteditable="false" isinlinelookup="true">
                                            <span class="ms-srm-LookupItem-Name" id="stan_servicecategoryid_lookupEditSpan" title="test" otype="10041">test</span>
                                        </span>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                            <label id="stan_servicecategoryid_lookupedit" class="ms-srm-Hidden-NoBehavior" for="stan_servicecategoryid_ledit">Enter a search term, then select the Enter key to search</label>
                            <input class="ms-srm-InlineInput ms-srm-InlineLookupEdit" ime-mode="auto" aria-labelledby="stan_servicecategoryid_lookupedit stan_servicecategoryid_w" type="text" id="stan_servicecategoryid_ledit" maxlength="1000" style="display: none;">
                        </td>
                        <td class="ms-srm-InlineLookupEdit-Box"></td>
                        <td class="Lookup_RenderButton_td" id="stan_servicecategoryid_lookupSearch" style="vertical-align:top;width:22px;">
                            <img src="/_imgs/search_normal.gif" id="stan_servicecategoryid_i" alt="Select a value." class="ms-srm-InlineLookupEdit" title="Select a value.">
                            <a href="#" id="stan_servicecategoryid_a" tabindex="-1" title="Select a value."></a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        <span class="ms-srm-Inline-LockIcon" id="stan_servicecategoryid_lock" style="display: none;">
            <img src="/_imgs/imagestrips/transparent_spacer.gif" class="ms-srm-ImageStrip-inlineedit_locked" alt="Locked control">
        </span>
        <span class="ms-srm-Inline-fieldChangeIndicatorIcon" id="stan_servicecategoryid_fieldChangeIndicatorImage" style="visibility: hidden;">
            <img src="/_imgs/imagestrips/transparent_spacer.gif" class="ms-srm-ImageStrip-field_change_indicator" alt="">
        </span>
        <span id="stan_servicecategoryid_warnSpan" class="ms-srm-Inline-WarningIcon" title="" style="display: none;" role="alert" aria-live="assertive" aria-atomic="true">
            <img src="/_imgs/imagestrips/transparent_spacer.gif" class="ms-srm-ImageStrip-inlineedit_warning" alt="Error" id="stan_servicecategoryid_warn">
            <div id="stan_servicecategoryid_w" class="ms-srm-Hidden-NoBehavior"></div>
        </span>
    </div>
    <div style="display:none;"></div>
</td>
```

Selenium:

```
driver.FindElement(By.Id("stan_servicecategoryid_lookupValue").Click();

new Actions(driver).MoveToElement(driver.FindElement(by)).SendKeys(Keys.Clear).Perform(); // This will clear the value of the text box
```

Comment: Share your code, HTML code sample, desired and current behavior. For now it's too broad

Comment: Can you do it not in automation?!

Comment: @Andersson - have added the picture hope it gives you some idea

Comment: @MosheSlavin Yes, manually i can do it.

Comment: Not really. This looks like a text input field that you want to click. Still not clear what is exact issue, what is your code, what do you mean by *"hyperlink"*... Share **HTML** (not image), your code, exception or misbehavior description

Comment: I think what OP wants to do is not click the hyperlinked text but be able to click in the text field to edit it?  What advantage does clicking it do though?  Can't you just sendkeys to it?

Comment: If you can click the middle manually and it do what you want then you can do it with Selenium. My guess is that you are locating the wrong element and clicking on it, e.g. the "test" hyperlink instead of the whitespace area. If you post the relevant HTML to the entire area and post your current code attempts and the results (errors, etc.) we can help.

Comment: @Andersson - Have corrected the description of my problem and added the dom

Comment: @JeffC - Have updated the information.

Comment: The HTML you have posted doesn't correspond to the picture. Please post all the relevant HTML.

Comment: @JeffC - Published the information. kindly, have a look.

Comment: Can you post a link to the page? Most of the HTML that you have posted is "display:none" or otherwise not visible so it's hard to tell what is what. The ID that you are using is clicking the text, "test", instead of the whitespace to the right of "test". You need to right-click in the whitespace to the right and inspect there... or better yet, give us the URL and we can do it.

Answer (score 0):

Use ACTIONS (or ActionChains in Python)

If you simulate moveToElement(element) and click(), it clicks exactly in the centre of the element. If the text is long and the above still clicks on the text, use moveToElement (with offset), giving it x-offset as required.

Java:

```
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.moveToElement(element).click().perform();
```

or

```
action.moveToElement(element, x-offset, 0).click().perform();
```

Python:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains as AC

AC(driver).move_to_element(element).click().perform()
```

or

```
AC(driver).move_to_element_with_offset(element, x-offset, 0).click().perform()
```